# How to create a cell with differents formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have to create a cell like and I am looking a way to do it with excel formulas or VBA code.

[image]

With two differents formts **red** to **green** or just **black**, but not in all the case depends If.

For example:

**Case 1**: If cell F1 and G1 has values the format is Red to green

**Case 2**: If cell F1 has a value but G is empty the final format in image 1 have to be Just black

[image]

Comment: You can add conditional formatting by the following rules: `AND(F1 <> "", G1 <> "")` format with red, `AND(F1 <> "", G1 = "")` format with black

Comment: But how to covine red and green in the same cell.

Comment: What do you mean by red to green? Color gradient?

Comment: Check in the picture 1, cell I1 with this format

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez you will probably need some VBA to do this sort of string manipulation and text formatting, because you do not have numeric values in the cells, but string values/expressions. YOu need to parse these out, convert to numeric, and compare to the reference cell, then set formatting on partial cell contents.

Comment: Sorry, my internet is blocked for that image. Can you send me a url with it?

Comment: I'd keep values from pic 1 into separate cells to use ordinary conditional formatting - but perhaps I always tend to simplify..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBA code should work. It goes into the `worksheet_change` event of your sheet.

I just set it for column I to change colors, but you can extend to J and K if you need to.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

If Target.Column = 6 Or Target.Column = 7 Then

    Select Case Target.Column

        Case Is = 6

            If Target <> vbNullString And Target.Offset(, 1) <> vbNullString Then

                With Target.Offset(, 2)
                    .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=5).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    .Characters(Start:=6, Length:=3).Font.ColorIndex = 4
                End With

            Else: Target.Offset(, 2).Font.ColorIndex = 0

            End If

        Case Is = 7

            If Target <> vbNullString And Target.Offset(, -1) <> vbNullString Then

                With Target.Offset(, 1)
                    .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=5).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    .Characters(Start:=6, Length:=3).Font.ColorIndex = 4
                End With

            Else: Target.Offset(, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 0

            End If

    End Select

End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```